# Error seeding JSON data with sequelize into PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

Occurs when I run the sequelize-cli command `sequelize db:seed:all`

When I try and seed an object as JSON I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Invalid value { viewId: null,
  dateRanges: [ { startDate: null, endDate: null } ],
  samplingLevel: 'DEFAULT',
  dimensions: [ { name: 'ga:channelGrouping' } ],
  metrics: [ { expression: 'ga:users' } ] }
```

This is my model

```
module.exports = (Sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Report = Sequelize.define('Report', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        is: /^[a-z0-9\_\-]+$/i,
      },
    },
    platform: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        is: /^[a-z0-9\_\-]+$/i,
      },
    },
    query: {
      type: DataTypes.JSON,
    },
  });
  return Report;
};
```

This is my seed file

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.bulkInsert('Reports', [
      {
        name: 'users per channel',
        platform: 'google',
        query: {
          "viewId": null,
          "dateRanges": [
            {
              "startDate": null,
              "endDate": null,
            },
          ],
          "samplingLevel": "DEFAULT",
          "dimensions": [
            {
              "name": "ga:channelGrouping",
            },
          ],
          "metrics": [{ "expression": "ga:users" }],
        },
        createdAt: new Date(),
        updatedAt: new Date(),
      },
    ]);
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {},
};
```

I was able to insert the same data directly with this query

```
INSERT INTO "Reports" (id, name, platform, query, "createdAt", "updatedAt") VALUES (1, 'users per channel', 'google', '{"viewId":null,"dateRanges":[{"startDate":null,"endDate":null}],"samplingLevel":"DEFAULT","dimensions":[{"name":"ga:channelGrouping"}],"metrics":[{"expression":"ga:users"}]}', '2018-04-15 08:55:12.449-05', '2018-04-15 08:55:12.449-05');
```

I wasn't able to find anyone having the same issue as me so I believe it is something simple but I cannot see it.

I'm able to run the seed with no problem if I wrap the object in JSON.stringify() but surely that isn't what is intended.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in creating seed file for sequalize involving DataTypes.JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55149411/error-in-creating-seed-file-for-sequalize-involving-datatypes-json)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encountered same problem
Just stringify your `query` field like

```
'{
   "viewId": null,
   "dateRanges": [
      {
         "startDate": null,
         "endDate": null,
      },
   ],
   "samplingLevel": "DEFAULT",
   "dimensions": [
        {
           "name": "ga:channelGrouping",
        },
    ],
   "metrics": [{ "expression": "ga:users" }],
}'
```

@Jaygles take a look at your sql

```
INSERT INTO "Reports" (id, name, platform, query, "createdAt", "updatedAt") VALUES (1, 'users per channel', 'google', '{"viewId":null,"dateRanges":[{"startDate":null,"endDate":null}],"samplingLevel":"DEFAULT","dimensions":[{"name":"ga:channelGrouping"}],"metrics":[{"expression":"ga:users"}]}', '2018-04-15 08:55:12.449-05', '2018-04-15 08:55:12.449-05');
```

you are inserting stringified data. So you need also stringify it in seed