# Error in creating seed file for sequalize involving DataTypes.JSON

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js, psql

I am using Sequalize for my ORM for my Node.Js/PSQL project.  I am working on creating a seed file to prepopulate my database; however, when I run the seed file I get an error related to one of the fields with the relevant information below.  There appears to be an issue with using a JSON object with

Error

```
== 20170308131757-examples: migrating =======
ERROR: Invalid value { example: 'mk@kWO5r' }
```

Definition

```
 const example = sequelize.define('example', {
    date: DataTypes.DATE   
    data: {
      type: DataTypes.JSON,
      allowNull: true
    },    
  }, {});
```

Seed File

```
 up: function (queryInterface) {
    const examples = [];
    examples.push({
      date: new Date(),
      data: {
        data: dataFaker.string({ length: 8 })
      },
      createdAt: new Date(),
      updatedAt: new Date()
    });

    for(let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      testAlertLists.push({
        date: new Date(),
        data: {
          data: dataFaker.string({ length: 8 })
        },
        createdAt: new Date(),
        updatedAt: new Date()
      });
    }

    return queryInterface.bulkInsert('examples', examples, {});
  },

  down: function (queryInterface) {
    return queryInterface.bulkDelete('examples', null, {});
  }
```

I have kept the relevant pieces of code to simplify things, so there are more fields and other aspects I can add if needed, and if there are small typos unrelated to the error that is likely from simplifying things, and I can fix those if found.

The issue seems to be that Sequalize is not accepting the JSON object in the insert, but it is defined as a JSON object both in the code and in the table itself(I checked).  I have tried creating the Json several different ways but outside of that I am kinda perplexed at this issue.  Is there an issue with using JSON objects with psql or Sequalize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize CLI has an issue related with the JSON type. I had the same problem and found the solution on the github of sequelize-cli. If I find the thread I'll update the source. What you need to do is to use `JSON.stringify()` because it will not accept the object as that.

```
examples.push({
  date: new Date(),
  data: JSON.stringify({
    data: dataFaker.string({ length: 8 })
  }),
  createdAt: new Date(),
  updatedAt: new Date()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because queryInterface is a little bit low level you have to specify that you're inserting json like:

```
return queryInterface.bulkInsert('examples', examples, { data: { type: new Sequelize.JSON() } });
```

You can get access to Sequelize object as a second argument from up function.

Besides you can use create method from your example model to create a record without any additional info like:

```
example.create({
  date: new Date(),
        data: {
          data: dataFaker.string({ length: 8 })
        },
        createdAt: new Date(),
        updatedAt: new Date()
})
```

where example is instance of your sequelize model defined