# When I use sequelize cli to do seed all，but it return error： invalid data？

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I use sqlite3 and sequelize.

- sqlite3 5.0
- seqeulize

My seed files

```
ERROR: Invalid value {
  show: true,
  itemAdd: true,
  itemsExport: true,
  itemDelete: true
}
```

My users-model contains：

```
itemList:{type:DataTypes.JSON}
```

My seed file:

```
'use strict'

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    {
      await queryInterface.bulkInsert(
        'users',
        [
          {
            ...,
            itemsList: {
              show: true,
              itemAdd: true,
              itemsExport: true,
              itemDelete: true
            },
            ...
        ],
        {}
      )
    }
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    /**
     * Add commands to revert seed here.
     *
     * Example:
     * await queryInterface.bulkDelete('People', null, {});
     */
  }
}
```

is there anything wrong? How can I deal with JSON data with sequelize CLI?

Comment: `itemPermissions` and `itemsList` are not the same name

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your itemList values and put it in string like this.

```html
'{
   "show": true,
   "itemAdd": "true",
   "itemsExport": "true",
   "itemDelete": "true",
}'
```

Check this link.
[Error seeding JSON data with sequelize into PostgreSQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49946600/error-seeding-json-data-with-sequelize-into-postgresql-database)

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer.
if i want to import json data to my sqlite3 database, just stringify it that can help.
so i change my seed file like this:

```
'use strict'

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    {
      await queryInterface.bulkInsert(
        'users',
        [
          {
            ...,
            itemsList: '{show: true,itemAdd: true,itemsExport: true,itemDelete: true}',
            ...
        ],
        {}
      )
    }
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    /**
     * Add commands to revert seed here.
     *
     * Example:
     * await queryInterface.bulkDelete('People', null, {});
     */
  }
}
```